Derivation and implementation of the logarithmic map of SE(2) to se(2)
I am a robotics student (FRC) trying to understand some code from a library that we use. I'm a high school student who knows some linear algebra but I'm struggling to understand how the library solves the following problem.
Background: Our drive system has four wheels that can turn 360° independently from each other and drive at separate velocities (called “swerve drive”, a type of holonomic drivetrain). We use this to control the robot's (robot-relative) translational velocity and its rotational velocity separately. Thus, for a short time (20ms) after we command velocities to the robot, it moves with constant translation and rotational velocity. This will trace out an arc over those 20ms (since the robot-relative velocity is changing as the robot rotates), causing skew.
Problem: We want to pretend our robot can go in a straight line while rotating, but it necessarily follows a curve between the time of our control requests. So we have to find a starting velocity and rotational velocity that over 20ms will create a difference in pose, $(\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta\theta)$, accounting for that arc.  The $SE(2)$ Lie group represents our change in pose, and we need to find the corresponding element of the tangent space $\mathfrak{se}(2)$ using the logarithmic map from $SE(2)$ to $\mathfrak{se}(2)$. $SE(2)$ is the Lie group that combines rotation and translation in 2 dimensions, so like $SO(2)$ but with translation too (and there are lots of resources online about the $SO(2)$ derivations). I don't know any group theory except what I've learned trying to understand this problem, so I may be getting terminology wrong.
Here is the math I think I understand so far: $g$ is the matrix representing an $SE(2)$ change in pose, which I can rewrite using small-angle approximations (since $\Delta\theta$ should be small) into an expression with the identity matrix $I$ and another matrix $\xi$.
\begin{aligned}
& g=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos \Delta \theta & -\sin \Delta \theta & \Delta x \\
\sin \Delta \theta & \cos \Delta \theta & \Delta y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos \omega \Delta t & -\sin \omega \Delta t & v_x\Delta t \\
\sin \omega \Delta t & \cos \omega \Delta t & v_y\Delta t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \\
& \approx\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\omega \Delta t & v_x \Delta t \\
\omega \Delta t & 1 & V_y \Delta t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]=I+\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\omega \Delta t & v_x \Delta t \\
\omega \Delta t & 0 & v_y \Delta t \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
& =I+\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\omega & v_x \\
\omega & 0 & v_y \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \Delta t = I + \xi\Delta t
\end{aligned}
Now I can write something like the exponential map like this by having $\Delta t=t/n$:
\begin{aligned}
& \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(I + \xi\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n} = e^{\xi t}
\end{aligned}
I don't know how to exponentiate matrices, but if I could, I think I could take the inverse of the matrix to find the logarithmic map too.  But here's where my knowledge ends.  Even worse, the actual code from the library (derived from Sophus) mostly deals with $\frac{\Delta\theta/2}{\tan(\Delta\theta/2)}$ and using their built-in rotation classes, so I have no idea how they came up with so much simpler of an equation.
Can anyone help me complete this derivation to find the logarithmic map from $SE(2)$ to $\mathfrak{se}(2)$? I'm prepared to learn more about group theory but I'd prefer a way without too much more theory if that's possible.

Logarithmic map is multivalued. You probably would not want to use it. It is unclear why you would need it in the first place.
